# VS Code IntelliSense Doesn't Autocomplete - python - How to define a method / functions that's associated to an object manually

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

**How do I make sure all objects inside `MethodA` below is known by VS Code for autocomplete to work when I open up `TestCaseScript.py`**

So, I have this `main.py` that define and associate a bunch of class/object into `self`.

`main.py` will import every single other script (lets say `TestCaseScript.py`) and pass this `self` as an argument so it can be use.

And inside `TestCaseScript.py`, the argument is accepted as `MethodA`

Example `main.py`:

```
self.LibraryA = ClassA()

Result = ExecuteTestCase (self)
```

Example `TestCaseScript.py`:

```
def ExecuteTestCase(MethodA):

    MethodA.LibraryA.FunctionInsideLibraryA(arg1 = True, arg2 = False, arg3 = 'StringA')
```

Side Note, I'm still a baby in python, so my general knowledge of a specific term is lacking that's why I'm having this issue, because I can't google the correct keyword. My issue is with VS Code doesn't auto complete.

Again, what I want is just for autocomplete inside VS Code to work so I can directly enter LibraryA by ctrl+click. Editing the current framework is not possible because everything work.

Comment: It is unclear what is argument `MethodA` of  `ExecuteTestCase`, but i guess what you want is to type hint the class that you `self` is from (and you didn't declared it here).

Comment: Also you might want to read pep8 https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/